# How to use other class() delegates and datasource func in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, picker, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITextField class which confirms to following delegates. I'm using this class as a global class (its a small custom library, which I'm using as a spinner).

```
    //MARK: PickerView Delegate
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataArray![row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.text = pickerDataArray![row]
}

//MARK: TextField Delegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let row =  self.pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
    self.text = self.pickerDataArray![row]
}
```

Now, I want to get the selected row, which in this class will be didSelectRow() func. So, how would I be able to use these functions in some way in those classes, where I implemented it?

Comment: you have created a custom class for it , better to create a class and then subclass it uiviewcontroller and then wherever u want just extend this class and then directly call these method

Comment: I'm giving this class as textfield custom class from storyboard. Will it be possible to do that @ShobhakarTiwari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using create Base class and extends in ChildClass or whenever you want to use

example:

**SuperBaseViewController Class**

```
class SuperBaseViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

   //Add PickerView's Data Source and Data Delegate Methods Here

}
```

**SubViewController Class**

```
class SubViewController: SuperBaseViewController{

   //Whenever you click on PickerView's row than it's delegate method in SuperBaseViewController if you add didSelect method

}
```

Comment: Okay, I followed it before and got correct, So, basically what you want to say is inheriting the superClass to, call their delegates. Thanks for the concept @Sunil